# Should this be mocked?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I am writing a component that fits into a large web framework.  The framework itself is not covered by any form of test.

The framework when initialized loads a large xml config tree (in memory) which part of contains xml for each installed component.

In my component I want to test whether it is recognized by the system and therefore installed correctly.

Should this be mocked or is it acceptable to check with the framework that my module is installed by doing an xpath on the xml config tree?  Or should that config tree be mocked?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "whether it is recognized by the system" ? Does this include your component talking to the system correctly ? The system calling your component ? What's the underlying technology ?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** you already have the code, so the tag `tdd` is not appropriate.

**2)** the scenario you've described fits under `integration-testing` rather than `unit-testing` - you want to verify that two components are working together. I imagine that the `system` does many other things beside using the configuration file, so you'd have to mock them all. That seems to be too much unnecessary work.